# Switching monthly to annual subscription in android and ios

Tags: cordova

I'm developing an app which is a tracking application using Cordova. So I'm planning to integrate subscription plan to my app. I'm having two products and  each product has monthly and yearly subscription plan. So my question is whether
am I able to switch monthly to annually subscription plan or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Upgrades and Plan Changes
>
> Users can manage their subscriptions in their account settings on the
>   App Store, or within your app’s interface. For each subscription, the
>   App Store shows all the renewal options that the subscription group
>   offers. Users can easily change their service levels and choose to
>   upgrade, downgrade, or cross-grade as often as they like. Downgrades
>   of any duration or cross-grades with different durations go into
>   effect at the next renewal date.
>
> You can check the receipt’s Subscription Auto Renew Preference field
>   to learn about any plan changes the user selected that will go into
>   effect at the next renewal date. (For information about the receipt,
>   see Receipt Validation Programming Guide.)

Source: [Working with Subscriptions (developer.apple.com)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6)

Comment: What about Android?